# how to str_replace Ѓ (cyrillic)

Tags: php, str-replace, cyrillic

How can i replace  the cyrilian sign `Ѓ` with a `<br />`?

This one doesn't work:

```
$card = str_replace('Ѓ ', '<br />', $card);
```

This one doesn't work either:

```
$card = str_replace( array('ѓ', 'Ѓ'),'<br />', $card )
```

Comment: A combination of [mb_strpos()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strpos.php) and [mb_substr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) then concatenating it all together again?

Answer (score 1):

Just few minutes ago searched for same function and found one from PHP.net comments that works for me.

Try this.

```
function mb_str_replace($needle, $replacement, $haystack) {
    $needle_len = mb_strlen($needle);
    $replacement_len = mb_strlen($replacement);
    $pos = mb_strpos($haystack, $needle);
    while ($pos !== false)
    {
        $haystack = mb_substr($haystack, 0, $pos) . $replacement
                . mb_substr($haystack, $pos + $needle_len);
        $pos = mb_strpos($haystack, $needle, $pos + $replacement_len);
    }
    return $haystack;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works (see http://ideone.com/hE72xA):

```
<?php
    $card = "Hello Ѓ";
    echo str_replace("Ѓ","<br/>",$card);
?>
```

output: 
    `Hello <br/>`

Comment: As the standard string functions aren't written to work with multibyte character sets, this isn't guaranteed